# PHP - setcookie

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have plugin and in my main class is this:

```
function test_handle_post(){
    //code
    add_action( 'init', 'add_Cookie' );
}


function add_Cookie() {
    $productname = get_name();
    $filename = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];
    setcookie('jeden','dwa');
}


function get_name( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_prop( 'name', $context );
}
```

And setcookie() doesn't work, because does not add cookies.
Why? Please, help me. I've searched so many pages with these problems and nothing.

Comment: Where is your code that gets the cookie?

Comment: Any error you get? How do you execute this code? How are you making sure the cookie is not created?

Comment: What is your input? What is your expected output? What was the actual output? What error log messages were generated? What is the code you tried? These are what make a good question.

Comment: So, my code is in main class. 
Folder (plugin)
  main class
I have upload file and i want save path and product (woocommerce) - so i use setcookie to save this. But i does not get any error it just does not save.
This is my code: https://pastebin.com/wr6CGYXS
(I do not publish this plugin)
When i use code @Bhargav Chudasama my product it does not display after adding the file. I do not know what else to explain.

Answer (score 1):

try with this one

```
setcookie("jeden", "dwa", time()+3600) or die('unable to create cookie');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Setcookie will set persistent cookie with following syntax -

setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure,httponly);
// here name  is only the mandatory all remainings are optional
// now you did not specify the value of expires parameter and 
// by default it's value is 0 means the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)

// following code set cookie for 30 days (60*60*24 = 86400 seconds in a day) and path is current url
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

Comment: let me know if you have any further question regarding your question. If you think this is correct answer then please accept as correct anser

Comment: Unfortunately, something like that happens:
https://youtu.be/7I0D7_uXp_o
Code:https://pastebin.com/xhVSfNq9